# Print only part (fraction) of a model

Tags: ultimaker-cura, replacement-parts

I've made a 9H-printing model tonight, and only a little part of it failed (because a support dropped off). I want to reprint only that little part.

How can I do that in Cura? **How can I tell Cura to generate a gcode file so only that little part (inside the transparent cube below) will be printed?**

[image: The part I want to print is the one inside the transparent cube]

I've placed the model upside-down on the Cura plate to "cut off" what was well printed. I've made a simple 3D cube model in Blender and placed it so it intersect with the part I want to print (I've set the "mesh type" of that cube to "don't support overlaps" for that). I've tried using "Mesh fixes: disable Union Overlapping Volumes" and the "Merge meshes" option, but the merge aligns the cube origin and the model origin (which I don't want).

What's the proper way to do such partial printing?

Comment: Btw, i'm not sure that I've used the "replacement-parts" properly, because it's a replacement part for the printed model, not for the printer (but keyword description is lacking)

Answer (score 10):

The latest version of Ultimaker Cura can do that (version 3.6).

I have built models made of different material in the same model.

How to do this is:

1. Select your CUBE and select the icon "Per Model Setting" in left side menu.
2. choice "Normal model", select the following settings: Top/bottom thickness, wall thickness and infill percentage
3. Very Important: all above settings must be set to 0!
4. Select the model you desire to print and select the icon "Per Model Setting" in left side menu
5. choice "Modify settings for overlap with other model" and select the following settings: Top/bottom thickness, wall thickness and infill percentage
6. Select the desired infill percentage and the wall top/bottom thickness for the portion you want print
7. slice the model

Note: If you need to print supports, then in step 2 select "Modify settings for infill of other models" (instead of "Normal Model"), and in step 6 also select "Add Support" and any other support related parameters you may need. However, Cura needs at least one "Normal Model" to slice, so to fool it you need to also another Cube as "Normal Model" with the parameters of step 4 somewhere else in your build plate (it won't really print).

Comment: As far as I can work out, this also suppresses the supports, so fails for models which need them. Or this there something I've missed?

Comment: This works perfectly even in Cura 4.8
The only I had to do was to apply step 3 also to Top layers and Bottom layers settings. Just setting the thickness didn§t work and the cube still included top/bottom layers. Setting these to 0 as well fixed it.

Comment: In Cura 4.8, the toolbar on the left doesn't have names to the icons (anymore?) - could you modify the answer and describe where to click in terms of "2nd from bottom", etc.?

Answer (score 6):

The [most recent versions of Cura](https://community.ultimaker.com/topic/16274-where-is-the-split-part-function-in-cura-321/) cannot do that for you. This is a removed feature (or better said: not ported from the old application to the new application), so installing an [older version of Cura](https://community.ultimaker.com/topic/10567-split-objects-into-parts/) may work for you.

Alternatively there are many more pieces of (free) software that can do that for you. E.g. MeshMixer or the Slic3r application can do that for you. [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=52DU7ZSRmR0) shows a demonstration how to do that.

Answer (score 4):

On Tinkercad, you can import your stl and add "subtraction" cubes, and merge them with the parts you don't want printed.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this helps but
download blender 3d, install
expoert your models as stl
import as stl file
enter into edit mode with tab key
and delete everything else
export as stl (maybe would have to set the scale to 100)

Comment: Hi, welcome to the 3D Printing SE! Please edit your answer and put proper punctuation or a bullet list (preferred) in your answer with the steps involved as the current answer is probably a valid answer but not very clear. While you're at it remove the typing errors :)

Comment: Indeed, that's how I proceed for splitting the model.

Answer (score 1):

What you can also try is to separate the part from the rest of the model within your CAD software. In FreeCAD for example, you can use the mesh design workbench to cut the small part away from the rest, then you slice this small piece and print it.